# Button Click Event Not Firing On Masterpage at Root Of Application

Tags: azure, master-pages

I have a TextBox (txtTopSearchBox on the MasterPage at the top of my ASP.NET Web Forms pages.

```
<asp:Panel ID="TopSearchHolder" runat="server" CssClass="TopSearchHolder" DefaultButton="btnTopSearch">
                                <label for="txtTopSearchBox" class="TopSearchBoxLabel">Quick Search:</label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtTopSearchBox" runat="server" ValidationGroup="TopSearch" CssClass="TopTextBox" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" />
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnTopSearch" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/MediaFiles/SmallSearchButtonOut.png"
                                    AlternateText="Search" ToolTip="Search" ValidationGroup="TopSearch" CssClass="TopSearchButton" />
                                <div id="TopSearchOptions">
                                    <asp:RadioButton ID="rbCaseID" runat="server" Text="Case ID" GroupName="TopSearchGroup" Checked="true" />
                                    <asp:RadioButton ID="rbClaimant" runat="server" Text="Claimant" GroupName="TopSearchGroup" />
                                    <asp:RadioButton ID="rbPostcode" runat="server" Text="Postcode" GroupName="TopSearchGroup" />
                                    <asp:RadioButton ID="rbVRM" runat="server" Text="Car Reg" GroupName="TopSearchGroup" />
                                    <asp:RadioButton ID="rbReport" runat="server" Text="Report" GroupName="TopSearchGroup" />
                                </div>
                            </asp:Panel>
```

When clicking GO, the following should be hit which directs you to the right case etc.

```
Protected Sub btnTopSearch_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnTopSearch.Click
        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtTopSearchBox.Text) Then
            If rbCaseID.Checked Then
                Dim intCaseID As Int32 = 0

                If Int32.TryParse(txtTopSearchBox.Text, intCaseID) Then
                    Redirect($"~/LoggedIn/Cases/View/{If(Products.GetProductShortCode(intCaseID) = "AF", "AuthorisedFunding", "Default")}.aspx?CaseID={intCaseID}", True)
                End If

            ElseIf rbClaimant.Checked Then
                Redirect(String.Format("~/LoggedIn/Cases/Default.aspx?ClaimantName={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(txtTopSearchBox.Text)), True)
            ElseIf rbPostcode.Checked Then
                Redirect(String.Format("~/LoggedIn/Cases/Default.aspx?Postcode={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(txtTopSearchBox.Text)), True)
            ElseIf rbReport.Checked Then
                Redirect(String.Format("~/LoggedIn/reports?Search={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(txtTopSearchBox.Text)), True)
            ElseIf rbVRM.Checked Then
                Redirect(String.Format("~/LoggedIn/Cases/VehicleSearch.aspx?VRM={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(txtTopSearchBox.Text)), True)
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

The trouble is that when moving to Azure AD logins, the button's code works fine from here
https://localhost:44300/LoggedIn/Default.aspx
but it does not get fired if I try from here (the root of the application).
https://localhost:44300/

Any ideas why?

The startup URL in Azure is
https://localhost:44300/signin-oidc
and logout is
https://localhost:44300/signout-oidc

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by adding a line in the MasterPage's Page_Load as follows.

```
MasterForm.Action = Request.Url.PathAndQuery
```